# Read header of other file and copy it into new file

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an html file something like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<css files>
<js files>
// maybe other things in header
</head>

<body>
// body contents ..
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to get header contents :

```
<css files>
<js files>
// maybe other things in header
```

how to get this section?

something like :

```
string header = HTMLFile.header;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/&ei=c5duUor7G8PVtQbnmYC4CA&usg=AFQjCNG2MH29eft1y8OrwFMjVzPNbVc0-w&sig2=klmIp99BtIYACV671D7DZg&bvm=bv.55123115,d.Yms) to parse html:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText("pathToFile");
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNode head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");
string headHtml = head.InnerHtml;
```

Result:

```
<css files="">
<js files="">
// maybe other things in header
</js></css>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Substring(string.IndexOf("<head>"), string.IndexOf("</head>") - string.IndexOf("<head>"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but HtmlAgility is better way i think.